# How to define default escape character in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, escaping

I have table

```
id  name
__________
1   name1
2   name2
3   _name3
```

and I want to select all names, that starting with '_' character.

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name like '_%'
```

But this query returns all rows from table. Maybe anyone knows some solution for this problem (without using ESCAPE keyword)? Or, is there opportunity to set default escape character in Oracle?

Comment: Why not using the ESCAPE-keyword? Setting an default ( if possible ) might result in unwanted results at other places. Using work-arrounds with string manipulations might result in poor performance. Plus it depends on what you want to achieve, maybe its better to clean the data once and deny the use of '_' within the data using an constraint.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, [you cannot](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52142):

> ```
> char1 [ NOT ] { LIKE | LIKEC | LIKE2 | LIKE4 }
>   char2 [ ESCAPE esc_char ]
> ```
>
> [...]
>   If `esc_char` is not specified, then **there is no default escape
>   character**.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select all names, that starting with '_' character.

Use `SUBSTR`.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1 ID, 'name1' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,   'name2' FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 3 , '_name3' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT * FROM DATA
  7  WHERE substr(NAME, 1, 1) = '_'
  8  /

        ID NAME
---------- ------
         3 _name3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
select * from table1 where regexp_like (name,'^_') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name like '\_%' escape '\'
```

Comment: Sorry.  special character \ is missing before _ and after escape within single quotes